# Ellipse construction

Tags: python, ellipse

I would like to construct an ellipse given the major/minor axes (or radii) and two points. I would like the line between the two points to be on the major axis. This just means that I would like the two points to lie on the major axis, and then construct the ellipse around the major axis. I originally constructed the ellipse at the origin and attempted to rotate and translate the ellipse, which didn't work. The unfinished code I have is listed below. How can I go about constructing an ellipse in this manner? Ideally, this would just return a list. Any insights would be greatly appreciated, and if you have any code for this please feel free to share.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

import math
from math import sin, cos
# Returns theta in [-pi/2, 3pi/2]
def generate_theta(a, b):
    u = random.random() / 4.0
    theta = numpy.arctan(b/a * numpy.tan(2*numpy.pi*u))

    v = random.random()
    if v < 0.25:
        return theta
    elif v < 0.5:
        return numpy.pi - theta
    elif v < 0.75:
        return numpy.pi + theta
    else:
        return -theta

def radius(a, b, theta):
    return a * b / numpy.sqrt((b*numpy.cos(theta))**2 + (a*numpy.sin(theta))**2)


def random_point(a, b, third_point, center=(0, 0)):
    angle = None
    if a > b:
        random_theta = generate_theta(a, b)
        max_radius = radius(a, b, random_theta)
        random_radius = max_radius * numpy.sqrt(random.random())
        f = round(random_radius * numpy.cos(random_theta))
        s = round(random_radius * numpy.sin(random_theta))
        angle = math.atan2(third_point[1], third_point[0]) - math.atan2(center[1], center[0])
    
    
    else:
        random_theta = generate_theta(b, a)
        max_radius = radius(b, a, random_theta)
        random_radius = max_radius * numpy.sqrt(random.random())
        f = round(random_radius * numpy.cos(random_theta))
        s = round(random_radius * numpy.sin(random_theta))
        
        angle = math.atan2(third_point[1], third_point[0]) - math.atan2(center[1], center[0])

        
    lio = rotate(center, (f, s), angle)
    lio = (int(lio[0]), int(lio[1]))
    return numpy.array([third, ward])



def rotate(origin, point, angle):
        #Rotate a point counterclockwise by a given angle around a given origin.
        #The angle should be given in radians.
        x = origin[0] + cos(angle) * (point[0] - origin[0]) - sin(angle) * (point[1] - origin[1])
        y = origin[1] + sin(angle) * (point[0] - origin[0]) + cos(angle) * (point[1] - origin[1])
        return (x, y)

#height
a = 95
#length
b = 25
#rand_p = (-random.randint(300, 400), -random.randint(100, 300))
rand_p = (0, 0)
points = numpy.array([random_point(a, b, (100, 100), (-25, 0)) for _ in range(200)])
#rando = rotate((0, 0), right_most_point, angle)
iopoints = []
  #  t = x[0] - (int(centroid[0]) - 100)
  #  t2 = x[1] - (int(centroid[1]) - 100)
centroid = numpy.mean(points, axis=0)
print(centroid)


#plt.plot(rando[0], rando[1], 'ro')
plt.plot(rand_p[0], rand_p[1], 'ro')
plt.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to ask a *specific* question. "Any insights would be greatly appreciated" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/), because this is **not a discussion forum**. Start by explaining: what is your general approach to the problem? *What happens* when you try using your code, and *how is that different* from what is supposed to happen? (This is an appropriate time to upload an image, so we can see your graphical output and your expectation.) Finally, *what don't you understand* about the problem in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ELLIPSE:
    def __init__(self, a, b, num_points, start, end):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.num_points = num_points
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.angle_gen = math.atan2(self.end[1]-self.start[1], self.end[0]-self.start[0])
    
    def generate_theta(self, a, b):
            u = random.random() / 4.0
            theta = np.arctan(self.b/self.a * np.tan(2*np.pi*u))

            v = random.random()
            if v < 0.25:
                return theta
            elif v < 0.5:
                return np.pi - theta
            elif v < 0.75:
                return np.pi + theta
            else:
                return -theta

    def radius(self, a, b, theta):
            return self.a * self.b / np.sqrt((b*np.cos(theta))**2 + (a*np.sin(theta))**2)


    def random_point(self, major_axis, minor_axis, center, qa):
            random_theta = self.generate_theta(self.a, self.b)
            max_radius = self.radius(self.a, self.b, random_theta)
            random_radius = max_radius * np.sqrt(random.random())
            f = round(random_radius * np.cos(random_theta))
            s = round(random_radius * np.sin(random_theta))
            lio = self.rotate((0, 0), (f, s), self.angle_gen)
            return (int(lio[0]+center[0]), int(lio[1]+center[1]))


    def rotate(self, origin, point, angle):
            """
            Rotate a point counterclockwise by a given angle around a given origin.

            The angle should be given in radians.
            """
            ox, oy = origin
            px, py = point

            qx = ox + math.cos(angle) * (px - ox) - math.sin(angle) * (py - oy)
            qy = oy + math.sin(angle) * (px - ox) + math.cos(angle) * (py - oy)
            return qx, qy

    def midpoint(self, p1, p2):
            return ((p1[0]+p2[0])/2, (p1[1]+p2[1])/2)

    def ret_list(self):
        points = [self.random_point(self.a, self.b, self.midpoint(self.start, self.end),  self.angle_gen) for _ in range(self.num_points)]
        return points
```